# Move questions to chat option

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some questions are better asked in chat.  I'm wondering if it could be possible to move questions into chat and have someone answer it (or discuss it).  When someone goes to the question, it might say "Question being discussed" and have a link to the chat room.

Maybe after the chat is finished, the results could be posted back to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chat is kind of a different beast in general though, isn't it?

Questions/answers are the meat of the site, and they have a well-defined set of rules/privileges.  Chat is much more free-form and less structured.  We might do better to promote the ability to chat more than we do, but to start broaching the question/answer boundary with the chat rooms via migrations I think is a step in the wrong direction and would degrade the quality and quantity of information on the site.